# Volume of the solid cut by a plane.

Tags: calculus, volume

> I'd like to find the volume of the following solid.
>
> The solid enclosed by the paraboloid $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and the plane $x+y+z=1$.

Actually original problem is the following (I made upper problem...)

The solid enclosed by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the plane $x+y+z=1$ and $z=-5$

In this case,

(the volume of the solid)=$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2} \int_{-5}^{1-x-y}dzdydx$$

**Now,** in case of

> The solid enclosed by the paraboloid $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and the plane $x+y+z=1$.

How can I solve this?

Could you give me some hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
z & = 4 - x^2 - y^2\\
1 - x - y & = 4 - x^2 - y^2\\
0 & = 3 - x^2 + x - y^2 - y\\
0 & = 3 - x^2 + x - \frac14 + \frac14 - y^2 + y - \frac14 + \frac14\\
0 & = 3 - (x - \frac12)^2 + \frac14 - (y - \frac12)^2 + \frac14\\
\frac72 & = (x - \frac12)^2 + (y - \frac12)^2
\end{align}$$

So the region of intersection between the plane and paraboloid lies over a circle of radius $\sqrt{\frac72}$ centered at $(\frac12, \frac12)$.  Now you can set up the bounds of a 2-d integral.

Comment: Wow.. then the remainder is following, isn't it? $$ $$ Let D is the domain circle you suggested, then the volume is $$\int\int_D{{((4-x^2-y^2)-(1-x-y)})} dA $$ $$ $$ Would you check it for me, please?

Comment: And I have some question concerned with paraboloid. If we cut parabolid with some plane, then the 'cut section' will be a circle always??

Comment: Your remainder looks good to me.  The intersection will be a circle over $x$ and $y$ except when there is no intersection (when the plane is too high) and when the plane is parallel to the z-axis (the intersection will be a parabola, there will be no enclosed volume).

Comment: $$ $$"The intersection will be a circle except..." $$ $$ How can I demonstrate this statement? Is there a geometric(not analytic geometric) method? Could you give me some advice, please? I am REALLY appreciate you.

Comment: When the plane is too high, the combined equation with the completed squares will look like $-C = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2$, which has no solution.  When the plane is vertical, the plane equation will have no $z$ coefficient, so $z$ can't be used to combine the two equations.

Comment: Oops.. I understood " except  ... " , but I wondering if the plane is "not" the case 1. too high 2. vertical.. its cut will be always circle. $ $ Sorry for ambiguous sentence.

Comment: Yes.  When the plane is not too high or vertical, you will always be able to substitute $z = ax + by + c$ into the paraboloid equation, and you will always be able to complete the squares, and you will always be able to put it in the form $C = (x - \frac{a}{2})^2 + (y - \frac{b}{2})^2$, so it will always be a circle.

Comment: Aha!! I got it!! Really thank you. $$ $$ For making certain.. We are talk about "shadow" domain, aren't it?? (NOT a cut section..)$$$$

Comment: Unless the plane is horizontal, the actual shape of the intersection will be an ellipse.  The shadow will be circular.